# How to use prolog to produce ideal list?

Tags: list, prolog

My goal is to put 1 in the list if the corresponding number is odd, put 0 otherwise.

```
even(X):- 0 is mod(X,2).
odd(X):- 1 is mod(X,2).
%This is used to determine even or odd.

determine([X|Xs],L):-
    even(X),append(L,0,K),
    determine(Xs,K).

determine([X|Xs],L):-
    odd(X),append(L,1,K).
    determine(Xs,K).
```

The ideal output is:

```
determine([1,2,3,4,5],K).
K=[1,0,1,0,1].
```

I know my current approach is very wrong, but I can't come up with an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make use of your predicates `odd` and `even`, this
is a possible solution:

```
determine([], []).

determine([H|T], [1|T2]) :-
    odd(H),
    determine(T,T2).

determine([H|T], [0|T2]) :-
    even(H),
    determine(T,T2).
```

I would prefer this, though:

```
determine2([], []).

determine2([H|T], [R|T2]) :-
    R is mod(H,2),
    determine2(T,T2).
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches, here I show you two. The first is the simplest (no need to use `append/2`):

```
even_odd(A,R):- ( 0 is mod(A,2) ->  R = 0; R = 1).

test([],[]).
test([H|T],[R|T1]):-
    even_odd(H,R),
    test(T,T1).

?- test([1,2,3,4,5],L).
L = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

Or you can use `maplist/3`, in a more compact way

```
?- maplist(even_odd,[1,2,3,4,5],L).
L = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```